# What is difference between 値段 (nedan) and 代金 (daikin)?

Tags: words

値段 (nedan) and 代金 (daikin) both means "cost" but im not sure where is a difference.

Comment: You can add 価格{かかく} and 値{あたい} to the mix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The meaning of 値段 is "price"and the meaning of 代金 is "payment"

For example, 「この本の値段は、1000円です。消費税を含めると代金は1080円になります。(日本の消費税は8％)」

値段は物の価格。代金とは、買った物の代わりに出すお金。

Comment: thanks but from that its not completely clear difference :(. thx though.

Comment: If you order two books which the price is 1000yen per a book on amazon site, you need to pay 2000yen and the carriage(500yen). 本一冊の"値段"は1000円で、あなたが支払う"代金"は配送料を加えると2500円です。


値段は物の価格。代金とは、買った物の代わりに出すお金。

Comment: I'm sorry i don't see a difference :(. I'm still begginer so i can barely understand that sentence u wrote in japanese but still dont see a difference between nedan and daikin.

Comment: Or are you implying that these words are interchangable? is one of them more polite ?

Comment: If you order two books which the price is 1000yen per a book on amazon site, you need to pay 2000yen and the carriage(500yen). The price(値段) is 1000yen per a book and the payment(代金) is 2500yen which is the price of two books and the carriage.

Comment: Even if you don't buy the book it has a price (値段) but you make no payment (代金). If you do buy it, the 代金 may differ from the 値段, as Yuuichi Tam pointed out, due to taxes, shipment, etc.

Comment: so 代金 can be also used as refer to additional price (or extra payment, final price, etc...)? is that only difference?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: I still dont fell like this question was completely answered so i wont check this question as answered. however - thank you all for effort.

Answer (score -1):

"Nedan" is a cost of individual item. 
"Daikin" is a cost of total order including VAT.