# What are the differences between 金、料、代、and 費？

Tags: usage, word-usage

For example, 入学金 is correct; we can't use 入学費・代・料; that's not 日本語.

But all of them mean costs for something. Could someone please explain this?

Comment: I feel like this has been asked before, but I can't find it.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean this question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/what-is-difference-between-%E5%80%A4%E6%AE%B5-nedan-and-%E4%BB%A3%E9%87%91-daikin It's a different matter though.

Answer (score 6):

The top few pages of Google search result already contain lots of fruitful answers, only if you can read them:

[「…代」と「…料」はどう使い分けますか？](http://homepage3.nifty.com/recipe_okiba/nifongo/060.htm) (Japanese)
[中上級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック](https://books.google.co.jp/books?id=0eprLex8sr0C&lpg=PA533&ots=4KFix_xBnG&dq=%E9%87%91%20%E6%96%99%20%E8%B2%BB%20%E4%BB%A3%20%E8%B3%83&hl=ja&pg=PA533#v=onepage&q=%E9%87%91%20%E6%96%99%20%E8%B2%BB%20%E4%BB%A3%20%E8%B3%83&f=false) (Japanese)
[JeckGroup](https://www.facebook.com/jeckgroup/posts/387185661362484) (Vietnamese)

The following is basically a summary of them in English, plus what little I know.

---

`～金`:
A general term for money in specific situations, not necessarily in exchange for something, might even not cost. It's a fallback option when none of the rest could apply.

> 保証金, 入学金, お祝い金, 所持金, 補助金, 契約金, 敷金, 賠償金

`～料`:
Charge or fee for activities done, typically charged by organizations with a predetermined amount of money.

> 授業料, 手数料, 送料, 使用料, サービス料, 通行料, キャンセル料

`～代`:
Price or charge in exchange for concrete (doesn't mean tangible) items. Most widely used.

> 食事代, 飲み代, タバコ代, バス代, バイト代, 電気代, 地代, 修理代

`～費`:
Overall expenses for specific activities, not used for detailed items.

> 医療費, 交通費, 学費, 生活費, 食費, 参加費

**BONUS**

`～賃`:
Fare or transportation fees, otherwise limited to a small number of idiomatic expressions.

> 運賃, 電車賃, 家賃, 工賃, 手間賃

`～料金`:
Similar to `代` or `料`, just preferred in charges for constant everyday services.

> 通話料金, 電気料金, 高速料金, 基本料金

---

So, your `入学金` is a good example of unspecified expenditure. Not only you in Japan wonder why and for what they have to pay it.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm just bad at searching for something, I don't usually get what I really want. Sorry!