# 「残業代」と「残業費」の違いを教えてください。

Tags: word-choice

皆さん、お聞きしたいことがあります。
**残業代**と**残業費**のどちらが正しい言い方ですか。そのほかの言い方はありますか。
教えていただけますか。

Answer (score 5):

As a native Japanese language speaker, although they are often mixed-up, I understand 残業代 is the amount of the compensation I as an employee request and receive from the company (employer) for my overtime work, and 残業費 is the amount of cost (payment) for the company (employer) to pay for my overtime work.

残業費 may be rephrased as 残業経費 or 残業代支払, but I cannot think up other alternative expressions for both words top of mind.

Answer (score 5):

## 日本語

前にも似たような質問（[What are the differences between 金、料、代、and 費？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21210/7810)
）に答えたような気がします。

一般に、「費」は費用（払うお金）にしか使いませんが、「代」はもらうお金にも払うお金にも使えます。なので、自分がもらうお金を「残業費」とは言えず、「残業代」しか使えません（もし、自分が社員に支払う残業費を相手から受け取る、という場面なら使えると思いますが）。したがって「残業代」の方が「残業費」よりはるかによく使われます。

他に正式な言い方として「残業【ざんぎょう】手当【てあて】」ということがあります。

## English

I remember I answered a related question before: [What are the differences between 金、料、代、and 費？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21210/7810)

Generally, 費 only means "expense" (what you pay) while 代 can mean both income and outgoings. Thus, if you mention overtime pay *you* received, you can't use 残業**費**; only 残業**代** is usable (but in a situation, say, that your client pays you what you pay your employee for their overwork, then 残業費を受け取る will sound fine). For this reason 残業代 is a lot more heard than 残業費.

There is a formal name of "overtime pay", that is 残業【ざんぎょう】手当【てあて】.