# How to say prices in these situations?

Tags: meaning, kanji, nuances, kanji-choice

Usually the basics only cover いくら so most basic lessons I know of don't even cover the word price in basic contexts.

I know 物価 and my understanding is that it is used in the general economic sense?

I'm trying to find out how to mention price in your general day-to-day product/services. Do services even have a different word compared to goods(e.g. hotel stay/massage as to food prices)? Would 価格 be correct? What about 値（あたい)?

What about "Well, depending on the price... I might be willing to do it." Would this "price" be the same as the commercial product/services sense?

What about a non-commercial sense of cost like "price/cost of living"? Same general economic sense but 物価 seems off since living isn't a product?

Comment: Related:  [What are the differences between 金、料、代、and 費？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21210/78)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We generally call price in products 値段、価格 and price in services 料金、～料.

Fares are called 運賃 and an entrance fee is called 入場料.

物価 means "level of price of products and services in an area", so we use it like 東京の物価は高い.

Cost is called 費用 and ～費, cost of living is called 生活費.

値(ね) is used for mercantile words like 卸値(wholesale price).

Comment: Also, 代金 (often abbreviated as 代) is often used for the cost of products/services, as in 「飲食代として」'Food & beverage costs', often written on a receipt.

Comment: Thank you Tam! Very detailed! 

What about in restaurants, how would you call the price of the total bill if they included service charge together with the food since there are 2 separate words for service and products (food)?

Comment: I think 料金 is more appropriate.